# I want to update a polygon with a click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what i want to do is when i click the button "Click me" i want the gray stripe in the middle transition to the right (fill the rest in) [quick illustration of how i want it to transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZNhI.jpg)    but i have no idea on how to do it since i have little knowlage to html, css & javascript.

Thanks in advance.

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color:white;
 overflow:hidden;
 font-weight: bold;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/PSr4n0g.png');
   background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.Shape{
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 0 0, 75% 100%, 100% 100%);
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;width: 100%;
}
.ShapeStyle{
    background-color: #20232d;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    filter: opacity(55%)
    ;z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="Shape"> 
 <div style="height: 80%;width: 60%;margin-left: 10%;margin-top: 10%;">
        <img src="logo.png" height="20%">
        <div class="ShapeStyle"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
  
  <div onmouseup="gray()">
  <button class="clicky">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
  
<div class="background">
          </div>
 </body>
    <script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); } gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'UA-73378277-10'); </script>
    <audio id="leson" src="music/music.ogg" autoplay="true" hidden="true" loop="true"/>
  <script>
 

    var play = false;
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("leson");
    
    myAudio.volume = 0.1;
 
 
    function onKeyDown(event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 32: //SpaceBar                    
                    if (play) {
                        myAudio.pause();
                        play = false;
                    } else {
                        myAudio.play();
                        play = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
      return false;
    }
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below. Note the addition of an extra point at the end of the polygon that I change when add a class:

```js
function gray() {
  document.querySelector('.Shape').classList.toggle("clicked")
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/PSr4n0g.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.Shape {
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 0 0, 75% 100%, 100% 100%,100% 100%);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.Shape.clicked {
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 0 0, 75% 100%, 100% 100%,100% 0%);
}

.ShapeStyle {
  background-color: #20232d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: opacity(55%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Shape">
  <div style="height: 80%;width: 60%;margin-left: 10%;margin-top: 10%;">
    <div class="ShapeStyle"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div onmouseup="gray()">
  <button class="clicky">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
```

Another kind of animation:

```js
function gray() {
  document.querySelector('.Shape').classList.toggle("clicked")
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/PSr4n0g.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.Shape {
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 0 0, 75% 100%, 100% 100%,100% 100%);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.Shape.clicked {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0, 75% 100%, 100% 100%,100% 0%);
}

.ShapeStyle {
  background-color: #20232d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: opacity(55%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Shape">
  <div style="height: 80%;width: 60%;margin-left: 10%;margin-top: 10%;">
    <div class="ShapeStyle"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div onmouseup="gray()">
  <button class="clicky">CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
```